# How to get inner html based on inner div height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per my requirement i'm looking for jquery code which could do pagination by html contents..
I did some research on it but didn't get any feasible solution for the same.

here is sample code what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child" style="height:30%">---contents-----</div>
</div>
```

now according to requirement I'm using below js code to detect if div is overflown.

```
checkOverflow () {

 let element = document.getElementById('child');

if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
    element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
}
```

- above function is returning true if contents are overflown on child div, now I want to truncate overflown contents to second page and add pagination on page so user can click on button to display more contents on second page.
- I don't know how to achieve above thing but I've tried to get contents position of **element.offsetHeight**, but that didn't works

Thanks.

Comment: I hope the following web page is useful for you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks! but it's not useful to me..I'm looking for logic of above question in javascript/jquery/typescript

Comment: I mean I'm looking for exact syntax or code which could help me.

Comment: How about using CSS overflow:scroll?

Comment: My query isn't on scrolling..my query is to check if div overflown then and then truncate remaining contents and display on second page.

Comment: How about using CSS overflow: hidden ?

Comment: so that just hide scroll nothing else :( I want to get all contents after specific height